# unable to see inital value at angularjs2 inputText

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am not able to see the initial value at inputText . I dont know what I am doing wrong but value should show the initial value as  I know before.

Regards
Alper

```
<input type="text" value="1" [(ngModel)]="Input.VSAT_input1" name="input1">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngModel` doesn't work together with `value`. You need to assign the initial value to `Input.VSAT_input1`.

The `[ngModel]="Input.VSAT_input1"` part of your `[(ngModel)]="Input.VSAT_input1"` assigns the value of `Input.VSAT_input1` to the `<input>`s `value`.

```
this.Input = initializeFromSomewhere();
this.Input.VSAT_input1 = 1;
```

An alternative approach to avoid overriding the value of your model with an initial value:

```
[(ngModel)]="InputVSAT_input1" (ngModelChange)="Input.VSAT_input1 = $event";
```

```
InputVSAT_input1 = 1; 

ngOnInit() // or whatever you use to initialize your component
  this.Input = initializeFromSomewhere();
}
```

Comment: thank you Günter.I assigned initial value in typeScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Input.VSAT_input1 = 1;

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Input.VSAT_input1" name="input1">
```

Comment: Thank you Yoav.I initialied it in typeScript